# created firefox extension showing unverified on install

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, signature, browser-addons

Hi I am trying to create a simple extension for firefox . I am using firefox version 44.0a2 . I have changed property xpinstall.signatures.required to false in about:config.I am able to install the plugin but its not showing on tool bar and this is the warning I am getting could not be verified for use in Firefox.Is there any way I can test my plugin without signature?

Comment: *"I have changed property xpinstall.signatures.required to false in about:config.I am able to install the plugin"* so where's the problem?

Comment: I am getting warning that this can not be verified and can not see on the tool bar.Dont know how to run it.

Comment: The warning is just a warning for installing an unverified extension. Are you sure that you don't have any error on command prompt?

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas- created .xpi file and installed via drag and drop.Coudn't find ny error that time

Comment: You have to get it signed, by either uploading it to addons.moziila.org as a listed or unlisted addon. Or you can use the self-sign API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution

Answer (score 0):

You have to get it signed, by either uploading it to addons.moziila.org as a listed or unlisted addon. Or you can use the self-sign API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Signing_API